# calculate the difference between two column aliases in a SELECT statement?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm not sure how to do the last part of my query, which is doing calculations directly with the aliases: (SUM(task_avg - minutes) AS difference.  I don't think I can do it as easy as I'd like, but can't find a means to do it.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT U.user_name, SUM(TA.task_average*M.minutes) AS task_avg, SUM(M.minutes) AS minutes, SUM(task_avg-minutes) AS difference
                            FROM summary S
                            JOIN users U ON U.user_id = S.user_id
                            JOIN tasks TA ON TA.task_id = S.task_id
                            JOIN minutes M ON M.minutes_id = S.minutes_id
                            GROUP BY U.user_name
                            LIMIT 0 , 30");
```

Comment: If you don't need to retrieve `task_avg` and `minutes`, I believe you can just do the operations all in one, without the two aliases, to get the difference...`SUM(SUM(TA.task_average*M.minutes) - SUM(M.minutes)) AS difference`

Comment: Even if you want `task_avg` and `minutes`; you can still use the method as mentioned by @andbeyond

Comment: Tried that and variations of it and got: #1111 - Invalid use of group function

Comment: Otherwise, if you need to retrieve everything, wrap your current query (without the `difference` calculation) in another `SELECT` statement that selects `task_avg` and `minutes`, then do your `difference` calculation in the wrapped query

Comment: I need some help...not sure the best way to wrap this.  If there is a specific function you can point me to, I can look it up.  Just not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. So I am going to go out on a bit of a limb here. I may have misunderstood the data model in the OP but as I understand it:

1) `tasks` holds a list of unique tasks

2) `TA.task_average` = the average time in minutes that a task takes to complete

3) `users` holds a list of unique users

4) `summary` represents users attempts at the tasks along with how long each attempt took to complete (through reference to the `minutes` table)

Gross assumptions out the way here is what I've come up with:

Firstly to get a list of all users, how long they took to complete each task in each attempt and the difference between each user's attempt and the task average:

```
select U.user_name,
TA.task_id,
TA.task_average,
M.minutes,
M.minutes-TA.task_average as diff
FROM summary S
JOIN users U ON U.user_id = S.user_id
JOIN tasks TA ON TA.task_id = S.task_id
JOIN minutes M ON M.minutes_id = S.minutes_id;
```

then aggregating that up to get the average difference from the task average for each user (which I think is what the OP was asking for):

```
select U.user_name,
avg(M.minutes-TA.task_average) as avgDiff
FROM summary S
JOIN users U ON U.user_id = S.user_id
JOIN tasks TA ON TA.task_id = S.task_id
JOIN minutes M ON M.minutes_id = S.minutes_id
group by U.user_name
limit 0,30;
```

If I have then wrong end of the stick then please ignore this. Thought I'd post it up anyway in case it is useful.

Comment: 100% on the money - exactly what I was looking for!!  Thank you sir!!